# Client side validation randomly not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to validate this model:

```
 public class LogonModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]   
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

In this action:

```
public ActionResult Logon()
        {
            LogonModel model = new LogonModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

In this View:

```
@model POCModelValidation.Models.LogonModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h3>username</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
<h3>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)</h3>
    <br />
<h3>Password</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
<h3>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)</h3>
     <br />
<h3>Email</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
<h3>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)</h3>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

..And I can't figure out the pattern in which it works, but it never works for the whole 3 fields. Other than that, if I fill, leave, then go back and delete the content of the fields enough times, it eventually works for all of them, but rarely on the first time, and never for all of them at the same time.
I do have these line in my `web.config`

```
...
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
      </appSettings>  
...
```

And in _Layout:

```
...
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Do you have any other pages with validation? Do they work?

Comment: @37Stars- No other pages, I just set up this project to test validation, I coded the absolute minimum, and it doesn't work (it doesn't work properly with two properties instead of three as well)..

Answer (score 0):

Load up Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  and ensure the scripts are properly getting loaded. If they aren't, validation just won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but as I said, validation occurs (although spordically), anyhow I re-checked and all seems well.

Comment: I understood that : ) My point is to repeatedly check this and narrow down when it fails. If you are watching the session in fiddler, and no validation is occurring, then there is a good time to alt-tab over to your running fiddler instance and see if the scripts loaded ok.

Comment: ooohhh That's much deeper than what I had in mind :-). Let me rerecheck and get back to you :-)

Comment: Well.. It seems all is well. One thing that gives error is that localhost:52182.js is 403 Forbidden. That is asked from Server:AmazonS3. I don't know What that has to do with anything but anyhow all relevant js' I asked for were delivered without error.

Comment: so far so good  : ) keep an eye on it with fiddler. if it happens again while fiddling, comment me back on here

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line to your code

```
<%Html.EnableClientValidation();%>
@using (Html.BeginForm())  


**Your code**
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, AFAIK this is not required in MVC 3. I tried anyhow, and still it doesn't work properly..

Comment: Amit - validation was happening on occasion, so the proper validation code 'is' there at those times.

Comment: I will check the MVC 3.0 for this issue.